# how to connect two machines together without a switch (opensolaris + linux or solaris or aix or hpux)

Tags: networking, opensolaris

I have two machines with same subnets  X.Y.Z.1 and X.Y.Z.2
I connect them directly with a crossover cable.
I can

$ ping X.Y.Z.2

from X.Y.Z.1
and the response is machine 2 is alive
but if I do something like

$ ping -s X.Y.Z.2

it hangs.
machine 1 is open solaris. 
Machine 2 has been hpUX, LINUX and Solaris Sparc
second test

$ssh X.Y.Z.2

connects and asks for DSA key, which I accept with "yes", then it hangs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems are due to not having dns working.  It looks like Solaris `ping -s` [hangs if dns lookups don't work](http://slacksite.com/technotes/ping.php).  ssh also tries to do a reverse dns lookup on connections so it will hang for a long time if dns doesn't work.

To make ssh work, you should be able to edit the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file on the server and add

```
UseDNS no
```

and of course instead of using `ping -s` just use regular ping without the `-s` to disable the dns lookups.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is hanging and not just timing out while ssh is attempting to do a DNS lookup? Try waiting 60 seconds and see what happens. I'll bet it works.